# Abrir ventana principal PyQt5(Python)

Tags: python, pyqt5

Tengo un problema y es que cuando intento abrir una ventana de tipo QMainWindow desde una ventana de tipo QDialog no se repleja nada, se supone que al dar clic en el boton abrir deberia abrirse la otra ventana pero no es asi. Si alguien por favor puede ayudarme se lo agradezco

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

class ventana_dialogo(QDialog):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(ventana_dialogo, self).__init__(parent)

        boton = QPushButton("Abrir", self)
        boton.clicked.connect(self.abrir_ventana)
    
    def abrir_ventana(self):
        
        ventana_principal()


class ventana_principal(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(ventana_principal, self).__init__(parent)

        #self.show()
        #self.exec_() # Al agregar esta linea me marca error


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ventana_dialogo()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class VentanaDialogo(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VentanaDialogo, self).__init__(parent)

        boton = QPushButton("Abrir", self)
        boton.clicked.connect(self.abrir_ventana)
    
    def abrir_ventana(self):
#        VentanaPrincipal()
        self.ventanaPrincipal = VentanaPrincipal()               # +++
        self.ventanaPrincipal.show()                             # +++
        self.hide()                                              # +++


class VentanaPrincipal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VentanaPrincipal, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("VentanaPrincipal")
        
        self.centerWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centerWidget)

        self.label = QLabel("Hello World", alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centerWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = VentanaDialogo()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]